# How to assign Rating value in Ratingbar in android?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I need to give rating for a product where everything comes dynamically.

```
    String rating = i.getStringExtra("Rating"); // the output of string is 8.6

    RatingBar txtrating = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rating);
     txtrating.setRating(Float.parseFloat(rating));
```

This gives 29 stars rated fully. But i need to give 10 stars where 8.6 should be assigned.

xml is as follows:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:numStars="10" // don't know why many stars are reproducing.
        android:isIndicator="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html):

> The number of stars set (via `setNumStars(int)` or in an XML layout) will be shown when the layout width is set to wrap content (if another layout width is set, the results may be unpredictable).

Basically the widget repeats stars indefinitely and you need to set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` so it respects the `android:numStars="10"` attribute.